# text-mask is not working for angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-material, text-mask

Trying to use

https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/addons#createnumbermask

```
  Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
    Can't bind to 'textMask' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("lex="18" fxFlexOffset="1">


        <input [ERROR ->][textMask]="{mask: numberMask}" type="text" [(ngModel)]="myModel" ):
```

I am using

```
"angular2-text-mask": "^8.0.4",
"text-mask-addons": "^3.7.1",
"text-mask-core": "^5.0.1",
```

Imported in my Module

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    TextMaskModule
]
```

trying to use in my component

```
numberMask = createNumberMask({
    prefix:'',
    suffix:'',
    allowDecimal: true
  })
```

my html

```
<md-input-container fxFlex="18" fxFlexOffset="1">
        <span mdPrefix>{{currencySymbol}} &nbsp;</span>
        <input [textMask]="{mask: numberMask}" type="text" [(ngModel)]="myModel" mdInput >
        <md-error>This field is required</md-error>
      </md-input-container>
```

Comment: have you properly imported createNumberMask: import createNumberMask from 'text-mask-addons/dist/createNumberMask' ?

Comment: I am doing import {createNumberMask} from "text-mask-addons/dist/textMaskAddons";

Comment: does it work if you don't use createNumberMask? This would show if its a problem with the addon or the masking all together. Does it work if you remove the mask all together? Should the input type be number instead of text?

Comment: it started working, I had to import `TextMaskModule` in the main as well as specific module.

Comment: does this stil works for latest angular version ?

Answer (score 1):

I had to import the Modul in the main Module as well as Specific Module of the application

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    TextMaskModule
]
```